# Table of trips from X to Y station with dates. Count the number of outgoing and ingoing trips for each station per day and store it as a dataframe

Tags: r, time-series, counting

I have an R data frame logging trips from urban bike stations into each other, the data frame has the following columns (structure):

```
Departure_station, Departure_time, Departure_date, Arrival_station, Arrival_time, Arrival_date.
```

I have the data for a 3-month period. I would like to obtain a data frame (or a group of them, but preferably one) which would allow me to, for each individual station, record the number of outgoing and ingoing trips as a function of calendar day in order to apply some statistical trend test (for each station) and the creation of heatmaps or incidence matrices.

I'm sort of rusty R-wise, and would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to check for correctness without example data, but using tidyverse libraries, assuming you have your data in a dataframe called `df`, you could probably do something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
outbound <- df %>% group_by(Departure_station, Departure_date) %>% summarize(departures = n())
inbound <- df %>% group_by(Arrival_station, Departure_date) %>% summarize(arrivals = n())
df_out <- full_join(outbound, inbound, by = c('Departure_station' = 'Arrival_station', 'Departure_date')
```